# knockout validation isvalid method

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Is it not posssible to use isvalid method inside viewmodel? I got error isvalid in not a valid function.

```
   function Student(name,age,country) {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = ko.observable(name).extend({ required: true });
            self.Age = ko.observable(age);
            self.Country = ko.observable(country);
        };
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /* View Model
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        function StudentViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.countries =ko.observableArray([]);
            this.errors = ko.validation.group(this.students, { deep: true });
            self.editingItem = ko.observable();
            self.isItemEditing = function(itemToTest) {
                return itemToTest == self.editingItem();
            };
            self.addStudent = function () {
                var student = new Student("New name","0", self.countries[0]);
                self.students.push(student);

                //  begin editing the new item straight away
                self.editStudent(student);
            };

            self.removeStudent = function (student) {
                if (student.Name()) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {
                        if (self.editingItem() == null) {
                            self.students.remove(student);
                        }
                    }
                }

            };

            self.editStudent = function (student) {
                // if (self.editingItem() == null) {
                // shows the edit fields
                self.editingItem(student);
                // }
            };

            self.applyStudent = function (student) {
                //  hides the edit fields
                //jQuery("#form1").valid();
                //alert(self.isValid());
                alert(self.isValid());
                if(self.isValid())
                    {
                    self.editingItem(null);
                    }
            };

            self.cancelStudent = function (student) {
                //  hides the edit fields
                self.editingItem(null);
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Knockout Validation plugin? If so, the `StudentViewModel` is wrapped in a `ko.validatedObservable()` and the `isValid()` method is on the outer validated observable. `self` points to the inner `StudentViewModel` and therefore won't have `isValid()` defined.